# Implementing custom loss function in Tensorflow leading to "ValueError: 'outputs' must be defined before the loop."

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, loss-function

I'm working on my first machine learning project in Python - using TensorFlow to try and syllabify words using the [Moby Hyphenator II](http://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/gutbook/lookup?num=3204) dataset.

I am treating this as a multi-label classification problem in which words and their syllables are encoded in the following format:

```
T e n - s o r - f l o w
0 0 1   0 0 1   0 0 0 0
```

When reading through [this guide](https://saattrupdan.github.io/2019-11-11-syllables/#building-a-model) as a starting point, I saw that the author used a custom function - they averaged weighted binary cross-entropy with the root mean squared error in PyTorch as such:

```py
def bce_rmse(pred, target, pos_weight = 1.3, epsilon = 1e-12):
    # Weighted binary cross entropy
    loss_pos = target * torch.log(pred + epsilon)
    loss_neg = (1 - target) * torch.log(1 - pred + epsilon)
    bce = torch.mean(torch.neg(pos_weight * loss_pos + loss_neg))

    # Root mean squared error
    mse = (torch.sum(pred, dim = 0) - torch.sum(target, dim = 0)) ** 2
    rmse = torch.mean(torch.sqrt(mse + epsilon))

    return (bce + rmse) / 2
```

I have tried to implement this in TensorFlow in the following way:

```py
def weighted_bce_mse(y_true, y_prediction):
    # Binary crossentropy with weighting
    epsilon = 1e-12
    positive_weight = 4.108897148948174
    loss_positive = y_true * tf.math.log(y_prediction + epsilon)
    loss_negative = (1 - y_true) * tf.math.log(1 - y_prediction + epsilon)
    bce_loss = np.mean(tf.math.negative(positive_weight * loss_positive + loss_negative))
    
    # Mean squared error
    mse = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
    mse_loss = mse(y_true, y_prediction)

    averaged_bce_mse = (bce_loss + mse_loss) / 2
    return averaged_bce_mse
```

On doing so, I receive the error `ValueError: 'outputs' must be defined before the loop.` and I'm not sure why as I define this function before I build and compile my model.

I'm using the Keras Functional API, and my compilation and fit stages are:

```py
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=weighted_bce_mse, metrics=["accuracy"], steps_per_execution=64)
history = model.fit(padded_inputs, padded_outputs, validation_data=(validation_inputs, validation_outputs), epochs=10, verbose=2)
```

Comment: Where's `outputs` defined?

Comment: @kkgarg I'm using the Keras Functional API as stated, outputs are defined as:
`model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)`
I'm certain that the problem isn't in the model building as it works perfectly with any other loss function I've used before (binary cross-entropy or mean squared error) - the error only arises with this custom loss function. Interestingly, the model also works when I take the mean of the binary cross-entropy and the mean squared error without weighting, so I believe that the weighting specifically is causing the issue.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a problem with the new loss function. Can you paste the error stack and the full code?

Comment: @kkgarg Yep! Here is the [error stack](https://pastebin.com/VUdXbBXP), and the [relevant code](https://pastebin.com/NzUZd7jz).

Comment: It's better to paste the relevant code and the error stack in the question itself so that it gives the complete picture rather than temporary outside links, otherwise other the community doesn't understand anything.

Comment: Thank you! I'm quite new to asking questions on Stack Overflow so I didn't know that was best practice, but will keep to that in future.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235402/discussion-between-kkgarg-and-rocketstar31).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the error stemmed from the operations that I was using in the custom loss function:

```py
bce_loss = np.mean(tf.math.negative(positive_weight * loss_positive + loss_negative))
```

This line uses `np.mean` which was causing an error - replacing this with `tf.math.reduce_mean` along with casting `y_true` and `y_prediction` to `tf.float32` via `tf.cast` solved the problem:

```py
# Custom loss function - mean of binary crossentropy and mean squared error
def mean_weighted_bce_mse(y_true, y_prediction):
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32)
    y_prediction = tf.cast(y_prediction, tf.float32)

    # Binary crossentropy with weighting
    epsilon = 1e-12
    positive_weight = 4.108897148948174
    loss_positive = y_true * tf.math.log(y_prediction + epsilon)
    loss_negative = (1 - y_true) * tf.math.log(1 - y_prediction + epsilon)
    bce_loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.negative(positive_weight * loss_positive + loss_negative))
    
    # Mean squared error
    mse = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
    mse_loss = mse(y_true, y_prediction)

    averaged_bce_mse = (bce_loss + mse_loss) / 2
    return averaged_bce_mse
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously, the error shown has nothing to do with the custom loss function. The code that you showed had numerous other bugs like not importing `tf.keras.layers` properly. After fixing those bugs, see the code below and test out on the versions below (works fine):

```
tensorflow 2.4.1
numpy 1.19.5
python 3.9.6
```

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Custom loss function - mean of binary crossentropy and mean squared error
def mean_weighted_bce_mse(y_true, y_prediction):
    # Binary crossentropy with weighting
    epsilon = 1e-12
    positive_weight = 4.108897148948174
    loss_positive = y_true * tf.math.log(y_prediction + epsilon)
    loss_negative = (1 - y_true) * tf.math.log(1 - y_prediction + epsilon)
    bce_loss = np.mean(tf.math.negative(positive_weight * loss_positive + loss_negative))
    
    # Mean squared error
    mse = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
    mse_loss = mse(y_true, y_prediction)
 
    averaged_bce_mse = (bce_loss + mse_loss) / 2
    return tf.math.reduce_mean(averaged_bce_mse, axis=-1)
 
 
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(15,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(64, 64, mask_zero=True)(inputs)
 
x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
 
 
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, kernel_size=1)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, kernel_size=1)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool1D()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
 
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu")(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(15, activation="sigmoid")(x)
 
 
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=mean_weighted_bce_mse, metrics=["accuracy"], steps_per_execution=64)
 
# history = model.fit(padded_inputs,
#                     padded_outputs,
#                     validation_data=(validation_inputs, validation_outputs),
#                     epochs=20,
#                     batch_size=8)
```

Comment: I think I made an error in the creation of the pastebin such that the last line of the loss function should simply be `return averaged_bce_mse`, would that affect the solution?

Comment: Nothing of the sort of error you were mentioning before, haven't looked at the loss function itself deeply though. Did the above solution work?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error of `ValueError: 'outputs' must be defined before the loop.`; I received [this error stack](https://pastebin.com/mFUAcfXi).

Answer (score 0):

In the below line of code:

```
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss=mean_weighted_bce_mse, metrics=["accuracy"], steps_per_execution=64)
history = model.fit(padded_inputs,
                padded_outputs,
                validation_data=(validation_inputs, validation_outputs),
                epochs=20,
                batch_size=8)
```

what is the length of your input data?
The steps_per_execution should be `len(input_data)/Batch_size`.
Remove the `steps_per_execution` and check again.

Comment: Removing `steps_per_execution` leads to a different error when calling `model.fit`; the new error is `TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int32 of argument 'x'.`, which I think means that the error is indeed with the custom loss function that I have written.

Comment: okay is the `steps_per_execution=len(input_data)/Batch_size`?...In the error stack trace that you have posted, the first point where the error occurs is `batch_size=8` right?....

Comment: `steps_per_execution` is 64 to speed up running time as it means that 64 batches are passed in one `tf.function` call instead of only 1 - it's independent of the length of the input data and batch size I think, are you referring to `steps_per_epoch`? I also posted my solution to this question, the problem being that I used `np.mean` instead of `tf.math.reduce_mean` and did not cast `y_prediction` and `y_true` to the datatype `tf.float32`.

Comment: Great!...you fixed it...I have encountered this before and was occurring due to `steps_per_execution` so I was asking you about it